# Eclipse Issue - Preprocess defined in .c & .cpp file are not considered during compilation

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc

I am using **Eclipse 3.8**, I am working on a LED panels having different configuration like common cathode & common anode. For this purpose I set some preprocesser directives as configuration in one of the cfg.h file as -

```
#define _COMMON_CATHODE_
#undef  _COMMON_ANODE_
```

Initially both the macros when set or reset respectively, it works fine. But later when I perform the changes on these macros I found the changes are not considered during compilation, as a result I am still getting the old data.

Some workaround -
If I do some changes in the source code Like altering text to display, then the fresh build will show text in oriented form.

I try finding solution for this but unable to get similar case.

Please let me know if anyone have any possible fix.

Comment: Avoid introducing identifier starting with "_" (and going on in CAPS).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with Codebench(it's roughly based on Eclipse).
Build version of software was stored in a definition, but if clean build is not done changes won't apply which bothered me a lot, not sure if there is a workaround with building without cleaning.
The only thing that helped me was cleaning project before building, so:

**Project -> Properties

C/C++ Build

Settings

Build Steps tab**

Add "make clean" to pre-build steps.

Since for you it's not something like build version, another solution I could think of is creating 2 configurations with different sets of macros definitions, that means taking your defines from source code and moving them to project settings.

**Project -> Properties

C/C++ General

Paths and Symbols

Symbols tab

GNU C++** or **GNU C** depending on the project

At the same screen create a few configurations at **Manage Configurations** page and set needed definitions for every configuration. Your object files will be stored in separated folders, so they won't get mixed up.

Comment: I tried with the 2nd option, still not working. I think your 1st option will work but I am getting error with "make clean" some file not found.    Also I realize changing the macros every time is not good idea. So, I created different projects for different configuration. As of now my work is on, but still I didn't fix the exact issue. Currently I am bypassing it using different project for different configuration.